# How to create a pairwise DTW cost matrix?

Tags: python, function, numpy, dtw, pairwise-distance

I am trying to create a pairwise DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) matrix in python. I have the below code already, but it is incorrect somehow. My current output is a matrix full of infinity, which is incorrect. I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

```
def calc_pairwise_dtw_cost(x, y):
    
    cost_matrix = np.zeros((len(y), len(x)))
    dtw_cost = None


    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
            cost_matrix[i, j] = float('inf')
        

    for i in range(1, len(y)):
        for j in range(1, len(x)):
            dtw_cost = cost_matrix[-1,-1]
            cost_matrix[i, j] = dtw_cost + min(
                cost_matrix[i-1, j],    # insertion
                cost_matrix[i, j-1],    # deletion
                cost_matrix[i-1, j-1])   # match

    return cost_matrix
```

Current output is:

```
array([[inf, inf, inf, ..., inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf, inf, inf],
       ...,
       [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf, inf, inf]])
```

Comment: For one, you don't seem to be using the distance between elements in arrays x & y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation there are several errors including:

- neglecting to make use of inputs arrays x, y
- cost_matrix is not declared with the right dimensions
- cost_matrix[0,0] should be initialize to 0

[Dynamic Time Warping: Explanation and Code Implementation](https://towardsdatascience.com/dynamic-time-warping-3933f25fcdd) provides an implementation of DTW that follows the Wikipedia pseudo-code closely as follows.

**Code**

```
def dtw(s, t):
    n, m = len(s), len(t)
    dtw_matrix = np.zeros((n+1, m+1))  # note the +1 added to n & m
    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(m+1):
            dtw_matrix[i, j] = np.inf
    dtw_matrix[0, 0] = 0               # [0,0] element set to 0
    
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, m+1):
            cost = abs(s[i-1] - t[j-1]) # use inputs s & t
            # take last min from a square box
            last_min = np.min([dtw_matrix[i-1, j], dtw_matrix[i, j-1], dtw_matrix[i-1, j-1]])
            dtw_matrix[i, j] = cost + last_min
    return dtw_matrix
```

Comment: How can we return just the cost? I tried returning `cost` and I get a float but it is incorrect.

Comment: @Julien -- can you give an example where the value of cost is incorrect i.e. `return cost` ?

Comment: US Brazil
2020-01-23 0.0 0.0
2020-01-24 1.0 0.0
2020-01-25 0.0 0.0
2020-01-26 3.0 0.0
2020-01-27 0.0 0.0
... ... ...
2020-08-17 35112.0 19373.0
2020-08-18 44091.0 47784.0
2020-08-19 47408.0 49298.0
2020-08-20 44023.0 45323.0
2020-08-21 48693.0 30355.0
Here is an example. When I load in those two series for as `(s,t)`, the cost I get out is `18338.0`, which according to my teacher is the incorrect answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's super messy. I'm not sure how to comment two long series in the correct format here.

Comment: @Julien -- DTW is for two time series.  Instead, you have dates intermixed with values which is a bit different.

Comment: I got you, I'm sorry I think the copy/paste mixed it up. In the actual dataframe, all those dates are actually the date-time index, and I'm reading in to `DTW` just the values for the `US` and `Brazil` series, which are actually two time series corresponding to daily new cases of COVID in each country from 01/23/2020 to 08/21/2020. So that should work right?

Comment: @Julien -- you should add the input data to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I would but it's not my question--I can write up one though if you'd like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241957/discussion-between-darrylg-and-julien).

Answer (score 1):

Under IEEE 754 rules, inf + anything is inf.  Since you filled your matrix with infinities, then read a value out of it and added another, you can't help but get an infinite result.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then! However I am referring to the linked pseudo-code below. I think I am misunderstanding of what happens when I get to the line where infinity is needed, or at least referenced.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping